# Form submit to upload file and also other fields using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have tested every question here and have also googled alot, but did not find the something that work.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="createarea">
    <form id="createform" action="index/create/createcontrols.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input id="title" type="text" name="title" size="30" value="Title"><br><br>
      <input id="description" type="text" name="description" size="30" value="Description"><br><br>
      <input id="keywords" type="text" name="keywords" size="30" value="Keywords"><br><br>
      <input id="link" type="text" name="link" size="30" value="Link"><br><br>
      <input id="file" type="file" name="file"><br><br>
      <input id="submit" type="button" name='submit' value="Create" onclick="myFunction()">
    </form>
    <div id="createformresults">
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
  $(function () {
    $('#createform').on('submit', function (e) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'index/create/createcontrols.php',
        data: $('#createform').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          document.getElementById('createarea').innerHTML = "SUCCESS";
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
}
```

MY PHP CODE:

```
 <?php





$db=mysql_connect('','','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("", $db) or die(mysql_error());




$title = $_POST["title"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$keywords = $_POST["keywords"];
$link = $_POST["link"];
        $image=$_FILES["file"]["name"];


        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {

        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";

        }

        else {

                if (file_exists("temp/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                }

            else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "temp/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            }
        }
}

else { 

    echo "Invalid file"; 

             }


            $qry="insert createcontent values('null','$title','$description','$keywords','$link','$image')";

            $res=  mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());

            if(mysql_affected_rows()==1) {

                    echo "Success"; 

            }  

else {

    echo "Not Saved";                    

}



 ?>
```

PHP code is working fine the issue is somewhere in js file.

Comment: why do you call onload inside of your `myFunction()`?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @13ruce1337 there is no on load inside function

Comment: @mega6382 im referencing the JQuery onload at `$(function(){});`

Comment: @MjrKusanagi there is no error and if I add any `alert()` or any other code outside the success it works.

Comment: @13ruce1337 I don't have expertise with jquery, I am less than a beginner.

Comment: Then your question is misleading. It says "the error is somewhere in js file".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `FormData` for this task.

Here is an example of your code using FormData :

```
$(function () { //On dom ready:

$("#createform").submit(function (e) { //will be triggered on submit:

     e.preventDefault();

     if( window.FormData !== undefined ) 
     //make sure that we can use FormData ie>9, chrome > 7, opera > 12 safari >5, android > 3  gecko mobile > 2, opera mobile >12 <- wil support XHR too
     {

         var formData = new FormData($('#createform')[0]); // use "[0]" <- important
    // you can append aditional values (regular text): formData.append("be","some value");
         $.ajax({
                 url: 'index/create/createcontrols.php',  //Server script to process data
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: formData,
                 xhr: function() {  },
                 success: function(response){ $("#createformresults").text("SUCCESS"); },
                 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { $("#createformresults").text(errorThrown); },
                 //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
                 cache: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 processData: false
          });
      } else {

          //Fallback

      }

      return false;
});

});
```

FormData will support multi file upload!

Add to your Form tag the attribute: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

**NOTE**: You may find that the `$_FILES` array is empty on server side page - In this case you need to make sure your server configuration allows file uploads, size limit of file upload is enough, post time
is enough etc....

The best way to begin is to make sure that file uploads is allowed and then testing with very
small files to be sure everything in your code is OK.

Comment: Not working I added `document.getElementById('createarea').innerHTML = "SUCCESS";` this line in success but it does not work.

Comment: You will need to show us more - php code - what is the error.

Comment: make sure you use my edited code and tell us what error do you get

Comment: I have tested your edited code it works. The success block is working but nothing is added in the database.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50086/discussion-between-mega6382-and-shlomi-hassid)

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is done!!

Add this source to x.html

```
//Program a custom submit function for the form
$("form#data").submit(function(event){

  //disable the default form submission
  event.preventDefault();

  //grab all form data  
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'formprocessing.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (returndata) {
      alert(returndata);
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

```html
<form id="data">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123" readonly="readonly">
  User Name: <input type="text" name="username" value=""><br />
  Profile Image: <input name="profileImg[]" type="file" /><br />
  Display Image: <input name="displayImg[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And this to a PHP file (formprocessing.php):

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$profileImg = $_FILES['profileImg'];
$displayImg = $_FILES['displayImg'];
```

I did it with the help this link 
http://digipiph.com/blog/submitting-multipartform-data-using-jquery-and-ajax

Answer (score -2):

ajax doesn't support file uploading at all. However, there are work-arounds. One of them is  a jQuery plugin called Iframe Post Form, read more from:

http://plugins.jquery.com/iframe-post-form/

```
$('form').iframePostForm({
      complete : function (response) {
           $('#createarea').text("SUCCESS");
    }
});
```

Apparently, you will have to specify the url action and `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `form` tag.

Hope this helps!