# unable to retrieve $_POST variable in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

After searching a lot and working endlessly on this problem I decided to post here.
I am passing a formdata with a filename variable to php using ajax. I then try to access the variable name so I can pass it to a second php that loads the name into the database. I am unable to pass or echo the data in php though. Can anyone help?

My javascript

```
function uploadFile() {
  var input = document.getElementById("picture");
  file = input.files[0];
  newFileName = elementHandle[9].val() + elementHandle[10].val() + elementHandle[11].val();
  console.log(newFileName);
  if (file != undefined) {
    formData = new FormData();

    if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
      formData.append("newFileName1", newFileName);
      $.ajax({
        url: "upload_file.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {}
      });
    } else {
      alert('Not a valid image!');
    }
  } else {
    alert('Input something!');
  }
}
```

My php

```
<?php
    $dir = "im_ges/";
    $file_name = $dir. $_REQUEST["newFileName1"].".jpg";
    echo $file_name;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $dir. $_POST ['newFileName1'].".jpg");
?>
```

Comment: Try  `var_dump($_POST)` on your php

Comment: Is your execution goes inside if(file != undefined){

Comment: array(19) { ["fname"]=> string(7) "dfgfdgg" ["mname"]=> string(0) "" ["lname"]=> string(0) "" ["addr1"]=> string(4) "dfgf" ["addr2"]=> string(0) "" ["city"]=> string(3) "sfg" ["state"]=> string(2) "DE" ["zip"]=> string(5) "23423" ["email"]=> string(17) "ssz3cdfs@dsdf.com" ["area_phone"]=> string(3) "222" ["prefix_phone"]=> string(3) "222" ["phone"]=> string(4) "2222" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" ["month"]=> string(2) "01" ["date"]=> string(2) "01" ["year"]=> string(4) "2000" ["medconditions"]=> string(0) "" ["explevel"]=> string(11) "experienced" ["category"]=> string(4) "teen" }

Comment: I actually tried the var_dump and do not get the required variable , but for some reason I can successfully access is in PHP using move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $dir. $_POST ['newFileName1'].".jpg");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form submit to upload file and also other fields using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522233/form-submit-to-upload-file-and-also-other-fields-using-ajax)

Comment: My file is getting uploaded to the required location with the correct file name $_POST ['newFileName1'].".jpg". but somehow if I try to echo that variable I get an empty string                                                                 $dir. $_REQUEST["newFileName1"].".jpg";

Comment: @Mona I'm a bit confused here. So you can access the variable using $_POST but you can't access it with $_REQUEST ?

Comment: I don't see how you're getting `$_FILES['image']`. You never do `formData.append('image', file)`.

Comment: Are you sure you're disabling the default form submission, so that your AJAX code runs instead?

Comment: Yes I am disabling form submission:

Answer (score 0):

Try this  sample  code

form.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
            contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
            cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
            processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
            success: function (responce) {
             alert(responce);
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form  action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><form id="uploadimage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
      <input name="name" value="First Name"><br>
      <input name="file" type ="file" ><br>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

create post.php

```
    echo "Name Value : ".$_POST["name"]."\n\n";
    echo "\n File Details\n";
    print_r($_FILES);
```

This will alert the values from form

Comment: Thank you Ganesh. The only problem is I want to upload phone number as file name to keep them unique instead of original file name that user supplies. Hence I added the code:

newFileName = elementHandle[9].val()+elementHandle[10].val()+elementHandle[11].val();

formData.append("image", newFileName);

          $.ajax({
            url: "upload_file.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data){
            }

Answer (score 0):

If you get the file name in your custom php controller the you can use

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";

$filename = "phonenumber.png";//Set here the new file name which you passed through ajax 

$target_file = $target_dir .$filename;
 // test here the file is moved or  not,
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
// if moved the file then update db with the $filename write code here
then update db with the $filename
}
```

or i changed the some code in above mentioed and add a text filed to enter a phone number and the selected file moved to the taget with the value enterd in the 
text field with name phone can you check is it usefull for you .

**form.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
            contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
            cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
            processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
            success: function (responce) {
             alert(responce);
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form  action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><form id="uploadimage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
      <input name="name" value="First Name"><br>
      <input name="phone" value=""><br> <!-- new field -->
      <input name="file" type ="file" ><br>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**post.php**

```
    <?php
    echo "Name Value : ".$_POST["name"]."\n\n";
    echo "\n File Details\n";
    print_r($_FILES);

    $target_dir = "uploads/";

    $uploadOk = 1;
    $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];


    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $target_file = $target_dir . $_POST["phone"].$ext; // here we change the file name before uploads 
             // test here the file is moved or  not,
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
// if moved the file then update db with the $filename write code here
        } 
    ?>
```

**create a folder in the root with name "uploads" and give full permison**